# How would you use readdir to create a list of files to require in a Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a director **data** and it contains 10 files and I'll be adding some files to it.  I'd like to automatically bring in these files when the node server boots up using something like
`let Test = require("./data/Test");`

I wrote the following, when I loop over it, I see the filenames.

```
fs.readdir(__dirname + "/data", (err, files) => {
   files.forEach((file) => {
     console.log("file", file);
     let fileName = file.split(".")[0];
     global[fileName] = require("./data/" + fileName);
     console.log(global[fileName]);
   });
 });
```

If I put a console log on the page and wait 5 seconds, then the data is indeed there.  How can I get the contents of this file BEFORE the server finishes starting?

Comment: If a source file requires another source file ... it's probably best to write that dependency statically into your code.  If only in consideration for the poor shmuck who'd have to troubleshoot your app if something went wrong after you deployed it ;)

Comment: Use `readdirSync` instead of `readdir`: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options

However i do agree with @FoggyDay